# Image doesn't change when I shake my phone

Tags: app-inventor

Image must change to another image when I shake my phone. Application doesn't work correctly. During shaking image just dissapear. Why?

[image]

Comment: did you upload the images 1.png, 2.png, ..., 5.png into App Inventor? What happens, if you do a right mouse click onto the set Image.Picture block and select Do it from the context menu?

Comment: Your accelerometer may not be working. Add another block to change a label when shaking so you can tell if that's the problem. You can also change the sensitivity of the sensor in the properties menu.